# Не отображаеться изображения в HTML

Tags: html, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде как код норм, но не знаю почему изображения в браузере не отображается.

Почему это так?

Comment: Когда нажимаете, ствите кавычки, вам автоматом добавляет двойные, сразу закрытые, пишите путь между ними. `<img src='images/e-commerce.png' alt='' />`

Answer (score 3):

Ахаха:) Ты вместо одной двойной кавычки ставишь две одинарные! Так не пойдет! Ставь двойные! на русской раскладке Shift + 2

Comment: спасибо :) я тупил

Comment: Кто. Пишет. Код. На русской. Раскладке О_О

Comment: Те кто только начал вкрстать